# Prove that $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n n \arctan(\frac{n + 1}{n^3})$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is to prove that $$\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n n \arctan(\frac{n + 1}{n^3})$$ converges.

I'm trying to use Dirichlet's/Abel's tests but seems like we have no sufficient conditions for their passage.

Is there any other ways to prove that this series converges and what I supposed to use for this?

Comment: It seems to me that $
n\arctan \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{{n^3 }}} \right)
$ decreases monotonically to $0$, so the alternating series test should work.

Comment: I also tried to prove this, but it there any strict prove of this?

Comment: I put $n=1/x$ and differentiated. The resulting derivative has the behaviour $1+O(x)$ near $x=0$. This means that $
n\arctan \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{{n^3 }}} \right)
$ is decreasing for sufficiently large $n$, which is enough. Numerically, it seems that it decreases for all $n\ge 1$.

Comment: Sorry, but what is $x$ here? We are talking about number series, not functional. Am I right?

Comment: Your sequence (without $(-1)^n$) is $$
\frac{{\arctan (x^2 (x + 1))}}{x}
$$ evaluated along $x=1/n$. If you show that the above function is increasing near $x=0$, it means that for large $n$, it decreases along the sequence $1/n$, i.e., the terms (in absolute value) in your sum are decreasing for large $n$.

Comment: You may have observed that $n\arctan((n+1)/n^3\sim 1/n$ and more formally $n\arctan((n+1)/n^3)-(1/n)=O(1/n^2)$ so that the convergence is obtained from that of $\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n/n$.